# Azure ServiceBus JMS transaction support not clear

Tags: azure, jms, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, qpid

I'm working on Java JMS application connecting to Azure ServiceBus. Once I found out JMS is supported I did not expect any problems. However, when I started creating the connections and added Spring `JmsTransactionManager` I got an error which said my Azure subscription is "Base" tier and thus transactions are not supported. What I did was upgrading to "Standard" tier and the error was resolved. This is covered [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/service-bus/).

However during testing I was not sure it is working as expected and I'm testing the behavior and in the meantime I got confused by another [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-java-how-to-use-jms-api-amqp#unsupported-features-and-restrictions) saying "transacted sessions" are not supported in this JMS over AMQP protocol.

Question:

1. Can I rely the queue in Service bus will be transacted meaning the message won't be removed from queue until my transaction manager explicitly calls COMMIT?
2. How can anyone claim JMS compliance but at the same time say I don't support transacted sessions.

Thank you for any response because I'm confused.

Update:

The Azure Service Bus starter for Spring Boot has Qpid as dependency so that is what I'm using under the hood - I was not aware of this first:

```xml
<!--Qpid-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.qpid</groupId>
    <artifactId>qpid-jms-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you're using [Qpid JMS](https://qpid.apache.org/components/jms/index.html) which implements the JMS API over AMQP 1.0, right?

Comment: Where does Microsoft claim JMS compliance? It's one thing to claim a working JMS implementation even with some caveats, but as far as I understand it actual JMS "compliance" means that the implementation has passed the JMS TCK (which Microsoft's implementation wouldn't).

Comment: Ok, maybe it is not claimed officially but there is lot of information they support JMS and that servicebus implements reliable messaging. Anyway what Im looking for right now is how to implement JMS/alternative protocol with the message protection support JMS addressed with transactions. Im working on standard Java/Spring Boot stack interfacing with Azure Service Bus. No Qpid JMS. The JMS over AMQP approach is implemented in Azure libraries as documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-service-bus

Comment: I read through [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-service-bus) you linked. At the bottom there is a "Next steps" section with a link to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-java-how-to-use-jms-api-amqp) which indicates that you need to use the Qpid JMS client. As I understand it, this is the JMS client implementation which Spring would use to talk with Sevice Bus (via AMQP 1.0). Are you saying you're using a different JMS client?

Comment: Also, the documentation you linked indicates you should use the [`com.microsoft.azure:azure-servicebus-jms-spring-boot-starter` Maven dependency](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-servicebus-jms-spring-boot-starter/2.1.7/jar) which includes Qpid JMS (i.e. `org.apache.qpid:qpid-jms-client`).

Comment: Also the main point is the confusion between those two statements - need to upgrade to standard tier vs claiming transactions are not supported. This is what is confusing me.

Comment: Ok, the qPid is transitive dependency so Im using it as it part of the starter dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not currently a specification for distributed (XA) transactions over AMQP and as such the Qpid JMS client does not offer an XA ConnectionFactory implementation so if you are using that then for sure you would not get any support for distributed transactions.

The Qpid JMS client itself does implement local transactions so in that sense you could use a standard locally transaction JMS session but it is possible that MS has disabled that through the spring boot bits to dissuade folks from using it as the benefit of local transactions is quite small especially for folks using spring how might think that they are participating in a larger distributed transaction when they are in fact not.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Im using the "Best effort 1PC" pattern, classic case of message driven DB update so I still need local transactions. XA or global tx I have not considered intentionally.  It looks like the local transactions work - Im just having another problem with Spring Integration core code, but that I will open as new question :) thank you.